# Run cmd from batch and pass new commands one by one

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I want to run a new `cmd` window from a batch job in jenkins and then hand over commands one by one to that new `cmd`.

I know I can start a new `cmd` and run some commands like this:

```
start cmd.exe /c "cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3"
```

As I have a lot of commands to execute, I'd prefer not to chain them as in the example above, but start a new `cmd` and then execute each command separately.

Is there a way I can achieve this? I know I could do that by calling a separate `batch` file with the commands, but some of my coworkers will only have access to jenkins and therefore we need a posibility to have a look into the commands and to change them.

Comment: start cmd.exe /c cmd1 and then start cmd.exe /c cmd2?

Comment: I can't do this, as the commands all depend on the first one which activates a python virtual env to work with.